# Edit datagrid without clicking

Tags: vb.net, gridview, ultrawingrid

I have a `UltraGridWinGrid` and I need to naviguate through it without using the mouse.
I can get to the grid with `Tabs`.
I can give focus to any rows with `Tabs` and `Arrow Keys`.

Once I highlight a row, how can I select a specific cell to edit it's content ? (All my cells are editable)

Comment: Post the code you use to give focus wtih Tabs and Arrows, it needs to be modified.

Comment: There is no background code..It is built in the grid. Where would you put the modifications into ? I guess this could point me out in the right direction..

Comment: I would have made the TAB key go to the next cell, then change the `DataGridView.CurrentCell` to the new one, and finally call `DataGridView.BeginEdit(true)`

Comment: Oooh I could play with that `Action` ..! Thanks i'll give you feedback on this. Try to put it in an answer format !

Comment: Okay, hope you will be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the code that is executed when the TAB key is pressed, you can do manually select the next cell and start editing like this :

```
DataGridView.CurrentCell = theNextCell;
DataGridView.BeginEdit(true)
```

You still need to calculate which cell is next. This should be easy, increment the column index when you press tab, however if you reached the last column, just change row and set index to 0.

For the arrow keys, you could increment/decrement column or row index, depending of the arrow, and apply the same code as above.